# Setting an AtomicBoolean again

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, concurrency, volatile

I am using an `AtomicBoolean` to enforce `volatile` visibility between threads. One thread is updating the value, another thread is only reading it.

Say the current value is `true`. Now say a **write thread** sets its value to `true` again:

```
final AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(); // shared between threads

b.set(true);
// ... some time later
b.set(true);
```

After this 'dummy' `set(true)`, is there a performance penalty when the **read thread** calls `get()`? Does the **read thread** have to re-read and cache the value?

If that is the case, the **write thread** could have done:

```
b.compareAndSet(false, true);
```

This way, the **read thread** only has to invalidate for real changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`compareAndSet()`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.java#L98):

```
public final boolean compareAndSet(boolean expect, boolean update) {
    int e = expect ? 1 : 0;
    int u = update ? 1 : 0;
    return unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(this, valueOffset, e, u);
}
```

[`compareAndSwapInt()`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp#L1172) is native already:

```
UNSAFE_ENTRY(jboolean, Unsafe_CompareAndSwapInt(JNIEnv *env, jobject unsafe, jobject obj, jlong offset, jint e, jint x))
  UnsafeWrapper("Unsafe_CompareAndSwapInt");
  oop p = JNIHandles::resolve(obj);
  jint* addr = (jint *) index_oop_from_field_offset_long(p, offset);
  return (jint)(Atomic::cmpxchg(x, addr, e)) == e;
UNSAFE_END
```

Where `Atomic::cmpxchg` is [generated](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/cpu/x86/vm/stubGenerator_x86_64.cpp#L596) somewhere at the beginning of JVM execution as

```
  address generate_atomic_cmpxchg() {
    StubCodeMark mark(this, "StubRoutines", "atomic_cmpxchg");
    address start = __ pc();

    __ movl(rax, c_rarg2);
   if ( os::is_MP() ) __ lock();
    __ cmpxchgl(c_rarg0, Address(c_rarg1, 0));
    __ ret(0);

    return start;
  }
```

[`cmpxchgl()`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/cpu/x86/vm/assembler_x86.cpp#L1211) generates x86 code (it has a longer, legacy code path too, so I do not copy that one here):

```
 InstructionMark im(this);
 prefix(adr, reg);
 emit_byte(0x0F);
 emit_byte(0xB1);
 emit_operand(reg, adr);
```

`0F` `B1` is really a [`CMPXCHG`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG.html) operation. If you check the code above, `if ( os::is_MP() ) __ lock();` emits a `LOCK` prefix on multiprocessor machines (let me just skip quoting [`lock()`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/cpu/x86/vm/assembler_x86.cpp#L1594), it emits a single `F0` byte), so practically everywhere.

And as the `CMPXCHG` docs says:

> This instruction can be used with a LOCK prefix to allow the instruction to be executed atomically. To simplify the interface to the processor’s bus, the destination operand receives a write cycle without regard to the result of the comparison. The destination operand is written back if the comparison fails; otherwise, the source operand is written into the destination. (**The processor never produces a locked read without also producing a locked write.**)

So on a multiprocessor x86 machine, the NOP-CAS also does a write, affecting the cache-line. (Emphasis was added by me)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. +1

Comment: TL;DR conclusion: `b.set(true)` or `b.compareAndSet(false, true)` does not make any difference at all for the reading thread. In both cases, it has to reload the value.

Answer (score 1):

Both a write and a CAS "touch" the cache line triggering the cache line to be dirty.

However the cost is relatively small, in the order of 30 - 50 ns.

The cost of the code not being warmed up because it hasn't been run 10,000 times yet, is likely to be far greater.

Comment: Why does a no-op `CAS` also touch the cache line? For example `compareAndSet(true, true)`.

Comment: @OhNoOh It could but on Intel x64, it doesn't appear to. For example, we use compareAndSet(0L, 0L) on off-heap memory to pull in a new page without altering it. i.e. pre-touch it to reduce the impact of creating a page on demand.